# Notification within BroadCastReceiver doesnt work

Tags: android

I faced an issue with Notification within BroadcastReceiver().
as I know, My code worked properly before but it doesn't work now.
sometimes NotificationTicker appear but no title and content has been appeared.
here is my code. my searches couldn't help me to find where is the problem.

here is my CODE:

```
private void MyNotification(Context context) {

    String NotificqationText = "NotificqationText";
    String NotificationTitle = "NotificationTitle ";
    String NotificationTicker = "NotificationTicker";
    PendingIntent MyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, Splash.class), 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder MyNB = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    MyNB.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    MyNB.setContentTitle(NotificationTitle);
    MyNB.setContentText(NotificqationText);
    MyNB.setTicker(NotificationTicker);
    MyNB.setAutoCancel(true);
    MyNB.setContentIntent(MyPendingIntent);

    Bitmap MyPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
    MyNB.setLargeIcon(MyPicture);

    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle MyPicStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(MyPicture);
    MyPicStyle.setSummaryText("Etude can makes our life Enlightened");
    MyNB.setStyle(MyPicStyle);


    MyNB.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle());
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle MyText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    MyText.bigText(NotificqationText);
    MyText.setBigContentTitle(NotificationTitle);

    NotificationManager MyNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    MyNotifyManager.notify(1, MyNB.build());

}
```

I used Toast message to find my broadcastreceiver works or not and find broadcast works properly and only notification has problem

Comment: as I checked again my code is true but some application like "Clean Master" had been blocked my notifications within my phone

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
private void MyNotification(Context context) {

    String NotificqationText = "NotificqationText";
    String NotificationTitle = "NotificationTitle ";
    String NotificationTicker = "NotificationTicker";
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Splash.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
    PendingIntent MyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    Bitmap MyPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

    Notification MyNB = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setLargeIcon(MyPicture)
    .setStyle()
    .setBigContentTitle(NotificationTitle)
    .setContentTitle(NotificationTitle)
    .setContentText(NotificqationText)
    .setTicker(NotificationTicker)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(MyPendingIntent)
    .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    MyNB.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    MyNB.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    MyNB.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    notificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), MyNB);
    }
```

Comment: thx Bro, as I check again my code is true but some application like "Clean Master" had been blocked my notifications within my phone.